# Класс по созданию табов(initActionBar())

Tags: android

Люди помогите, пытаюсь механизм создания табов вынести в отдельный класс, но ничего не выходит.

```
public class TabMain extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

public void add(){

ActionBar bar = getActionBar();//Ошибка здесь TabMain(Activity).initActionBar()--->window=0

    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = bar.newTab();
    tab.setText(R.string.tab_menu_1);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tab);

    tab = bar.newTab();
    tab.setText(R.string.tab_menu_2);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tab);

    tab = bar.newTab();
    tab.setText(R.string.tab_menu_3);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(tab);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Ничего не выходит = падает? не отображается? отображается не так как хочется?

Comment: Вы наследуетесь от Sherlock, значит Вам нужно вызвать метод getSupportActionBar().